# vba autofilter rows A1 vs A2

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, compare, autofilter

The (current Excel VBA) autofilter below compares a column to two values. This is easy as it compares each value to JUST ONE external value (or another).
Question: what can I xlOr argument can I add to compare each cell to the next: A1 (expect float values)

```
    .AutoFilter 1, "<" & thisCell.Offset(0, 29).Value * (1 - thisCell.Offset(0, 30).Value), _
    xlOr, ">" & thisCell.Offset(0, 29).Value * (1 + thisCell.Offset(0, 31).Value) '29,30,29,31
```

I can do a for loop but that would be way slower. I'm open to any non-loop-every-value options that might be fast enough.
(ps. I did search for some options as well. no luck...)

Comment: [MS AutoFilter documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) shows there are up to two criteria parameters  and an `Operator` one. Go with them.

Comment: I'm not sure how your answer applies. I'm already using autofilter and I'm trying to compare one value to the next.